# Nothing showing under PHP and mySQL <tr>

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, html-table

I'm looping a table with mySQL and with a while function and the table builds all the table headers and the loop, but nothing under the loop. I have a `<?php endwhile ?>` after the loop but it won't display anything under that. It will echo more than one tr from the database but I loose the rest of the page!

```
<?php
$inttotalcredits = 0;

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM site_products JOIN site_trans ON site_products.product_id = site_trans.trans_product");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die(mysql_error())) :
?>

<tr>
   <td><center><?php echo $row['product_id'] ?></center></td>
   <td><center><?php echo $row['product_name'] ?></center></td>
   <td><center><?php echo $row['product_number'] ?></center></td>
   <td><center><?php echo $row['product_description'] ?></center></td>
   <td><center><?php echo $row['trans_inventory'] ?></center></td>
   <?php
$inttotalcredits += $row['trans_inventory']; ?>
</tr>

<?php endwhile ?>
</table>
<center><?php echo $inttotalcredits ?></center>
</p><p><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></p>
```

Comment: Show us the code for the loop itself.

Comment: Sorry but `No code, no help`!

Comment: We can't help you, as you didn't put any source code here.  Read the FAQ:  http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: That's far and away the most simultaneous "show us your code" comments I've ever seen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't call `die()` while fetching results.  `mysql_fetch_array()` returns false when you reach the end of the result set an no more results are available, which triggers your `die()` call and cancels execution of the rest of your script.

```
// Don't do this:
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die(mysql_error()))

// Instead do this:
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
```

It is recommended (and an important habit to get into) to wrap your database output in `htmlspecialchars()` to encode any `<>&` etc that they may include, but also to protect against cross-site scripting attacks when displaying user-input.

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['product_name']); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm pretty new to mysql so this is a giant help! I had asked somewhere else and they recommended added the or die to find the error - not asking there again.

Comment: @OliverWhysall Using the `or die()` idiom is common to test if a connection was successfully made or if a query was successful, but can't be used when fetching results.